# UFT 14.03 - Calling Web Service with data from XML only runs the first record. How come?

Tags: xml, hp-uft, uft-api, uft14

I am a newbie to UFT and I am  following the examples in the UFT 14.03 tutorial to call web services (https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Tutorial.pdf)

The tutorial has the web service data being populated from an Excel file. I took the flights data in the Excel file and turned it into an Xml file. I then changed the Data input setting to XML and loaded the flights.xml file. It showed up under Data as Current Test -> flights and listed the 8 records

- I set the DataSource for the TestFlow to flights. I then set it to start at First Row and increment by 1 till it gets to the Last Row. Action is set to WrapAround.
- I set the parameters for the GetFlights and CreateFlightOrder calls exactly the same way in the book.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADZDZ.gif)

Here is the Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <CustomerName type="xs:string">Ann Frank</CustomerName>
        <FlightNumber type="xs:integer">1089</FlightNumber>
        <NumberOfTickets type="xs:integer">3</NumberOfTickets>
        <Class type="xs:string">Economy</Class>
        <DepartureDate type="xs:dateTime">2115-06-01T09:00:00</DepartureDate>  
        <DepartureCity type="xs:string">Denver</DepartureCity>
        <ArrivalCity type="xs:string">Seattle</ArrivalCity>
        <OrderNumber type="xs:integer" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Price type="xs:decimal">196.4</Price>
    </record>   
    <record>
        <CustomerName type="xs:string">John Parker</CustomerName>
        <FlightNumber type="xs:integer">1042</FlightNumber>
        <NumberOfTickets type="xs:integer">1</NumberOfTickets>
        <Class type="xs:string">Business</Class>
        <DepartureDate type="xs:dateTime">2115-07-01T09:00:00</DepartureDate>
        <DepartureCity type="xs:string">San Francisco</DepartureCity>
        <ArrivalCity type="xs:string">Los Angeles</ArrivalCity>
        <OrderNumber type="xs:integer" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Price type="xs:decimal">124.8</Price>
    </record>
```

.. 6 more records

When I run the test, it only executes the first record

```
<record>
    <CustomerName type="xs:string">Ann Frank</CustomerName>
    <FlightNumber type="xs:integer">1089</FlightNumber>
    <NumberOfTickets type="xs:integer">3</NumberOfTickets>
    <Class type="xs:string">Economy</Class>
    <DepartureDate type="xs:dateTime">2115-06-01T09:00:00</DepartureDate>
    <DepartureCity type="xs:string">Denver</DepartureCity>
    <ArrivalCity type="xs:string">Seattle</ArrivalCity>
    <Price type="xs:decimal">196.4</Price>
</record>
```

and stops. Testflow is showing the End row as 1. It should be 8 since there are 8 records in the Xml file. For some reason, the Testflow is seeing only the first record even though there are 8 records in the Data section.

LoadXML is coming back with a
"Failed validating schema. Xml document is not fully validated." error but does not give any other useful information.

Why is this happening? I would appreciate your help with this.

Thank you.

Burak